# How to find "Cursor" position in webpage with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I just started learning Selenium Webdriver using java Script, the question what I have asked might me a silly one. But still wanted to know whether it is possible or not.

As per my question, please go through the below example

In any Login page, enter valid "Username" and click on "signin" button, it throws an error message "Please enter password" and the "cursor" will be located in "Password" field

So, we can get the error message via code. Now, how can we locate or identify the "Cursor" position in the webpage via code?

Comment: to clarify, are you asking 1) which element on the page has the focus, or 2) in a textbox, where the cursor is located (i.e., at the beginning vs. at the end of existing text)?

Answer (score 5):

By definition, any widget that has focus also has the cursor. So driver.switchTo().activeElement() will return the currently focused WebElement. It doesn't actually change anything, just returns the active element.  You can call

```
expectedElement.equals(driver.switchTo().activeElement());
```

to verify that expectedElement has focus.

Comment: I know that the question was asked more than a year ago. I just thought it should have an answer. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hey user3313128 with Selenium Web driver library it is only possible to figure out the current position by knowing the last place you moved it to.

Javascript sadly dose not give you an option to quickly get the X & Y.

An easy work around this is to simple run an simple function in the browser

```
async function (){
    await this.driver.executeScript(function(  ) { 
        let mouse = { x:0, y:0 }
        onmousemove = function(e){ mouse.x = e.clientX, mouse.y = e.clientY }
    })
}
```

this function will track your mouses X and Y in the browser the whole time

Then when you need to know mouse's location just call this script

```
mouse = driver.executeScript( function (){return mouse})
```

although the smart move is to track all of this within your JS on the server side at each mouse move and click().