# C# Selenium ExecuteScript Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

i'm trying to assigning a job for "onmousemove" of selenium driver but i'm not able to do it.
It works fine when i assign this job with using Selenium Driver's Webbrowser (Chrome's) "console" option for developer tools just simply copy paste of that code
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxk1y.png)

```
    let mouse = { x:0, y:0 }
    onmousemove = function(e){ mouse.x = e.clientX, mouse.y = e.clientY }
```

Then i'm able to follow values for "mouse" on console so this code works fine.
But when i try to apply this code with using my app it doesn't work.

```
ele = (IWebElement)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var setFunc2 = function(){" +
                   "let mouse = { x:0, y: 0 };" +
                   "onmousemove = function(e){  mouse.x = e.clientX, mouse.y = e.clientY};" +
                   "return document.elementFromPoint(mouse.x,mouse.y)" +
                   "}");
```

I just wanted to do https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484308/15439917 similiar thing like as this topic.

Comment: You are trying to run Java code in c#.  They are not the same language.  Try using in c# the class Process to run a console command.

Comment: I know they aren't same language that's why Selenium has ability to running javascript codes but i think my script code isn't work because of i'm not doing it in a right way so that's why i've asked to people how can i fix my issue

Comment: What is your interface between Net and Selenium?  You are trying to run Selenium from inside Net which will never work.   Run Selenium from a console which what you would do using the Net Process class.

Comment: whats the behvior in console , you are not calling that fucntion just defining it .

Comment: @jdweng sir i'm talking about console of Selenium Driver's (Chrome's) developer tools, i mean i'm using selenium with Windows Forms App and i'm manually paste that code into webbrowser's developertools -> Console and it works fine.

Comment: @PDHide yes sir when i run script from console of webbrowser manually then my function stays in memory permanently so that function always following mouse coordinates so i'm able to get coordinates whenever i want when i call "return mouse". But if i inject my code via my C# forms app my codes isn't stays in memory so i can't reach that variables again. All i need to do is just write this funtions "permanent" to memory via my forms app

Comment: In memory of what ? Chrome instance ?

Comment: Each selenium run starts a new fresh chrome instance so state won't be saved unless you use the same userdir and profile for all runs

Comment: @Klaujesc1, The syntax for `JavaScriptExecutor` seems to be ok. However, the JS function itself is being created and assigned to `setFunc2`. Can you please check if this is being called at all?

WebElement is not returned until the function itself is called.

Comment: If code work from console then run from Process Class. IJavaScriptExecutor may not be not what the latest version of Chrome is using.  Not all Java is the same.  That is why you often need in a Request the UserAgent which specifies the Browser that you are using.